# Rstudio: ajuste de decimales en la función de “corr.test”

Tags: r

Estoy intentando obtener (en R studio) los valores de r, r^2 y p valor que obtengo con la función corr.test:

```
    Reg.rawdata<-dataframe(Rawdata$Abundance,Rawdata$Infected,Rawdata$Prevalence)
     library("psych")
    corr.test(Reg.rawdata,use="complete",method="pearson")
```

Esta función me los da pero solo con dos decimales. Me gustaría que el p valor sea el exactos (con los decimales que sean necesarios).

¿Alguien sabría decirme como puedo obtenerlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que ves en tu consola después de ejecutar `corr.test()` es un sumario que esa función produce a partir de la prueba. En ese sumario se muestran lo p value con dos decimales porque le pareció buena idea al programador/a. Sin embargo la función `corr.test()` produce al mismo tiempo su verdadero output en formato lista. Dentro de esa lista hay un elemento que que se llama `p` y es una matríz con los p-value con todos los decimales que se calcularon. Creo que eso es lo que estás buscando.

## Ejemplo:

Primero creo un data.frame con tres columnas numéricas aleatorias, porque no incluiste tus datos `:(`.  Le asigno el nombre `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10, 1, 2), b=rnorm(10, 1, 2), c=rnorm(10, 1, 2))
```

Realizo la prueba y le asigno un nombre al resultado con el operador <-

```
resultado_corr.test <- corr.test(df)
```

Acá viene la parte curiosa: si escribes en la consola (y das enter) el nombre del objeto `resultado_corr.test` R va a "mirar" si hay algún método específico para imprimirlo en pantalla. Como en este caso lo encuentra, lo usa, y lo que te muestra es lo que ese método le pasa formateado. Para este ejemplo el sumario de un objeto `corr.test`.
Esto NO es lo que querés, entoces lo que sigue es ver que hay dentro de ese objeto y buscar ahí el cantidad de interés, por ejemplo, los p value. 
Eso lo podemos hacer con las funciones `str()` o con `View()` en Rstudio. Atento a las mayúsculas de `View()`.

```
str(resultado_corr.test)             
View(resultado_corr.test)
```

Con str() o View() encontramos que los p-value se guardan en el elemento `p` de la lista. También es buena idea revisar la ayuda de la función que estamos usando con `help(corr.test)`. En general todas las ayudas incluyen el detalle del output que produce la función y no hay que estar adivinando dónde está lo que buscamos.

Sabiendo donde están las cantidades de interés podemos verlas haciendo un subset con el operador `$`.

```
resultado_corr.test$p 

          a         b         c
a 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.9414547
b 0.7494632 0.0000000 1.0000000
c 0.3138182 0.8566343 0.0000000
```

A
Como es subconjunto ya no es un objeto de la clase `corr.test` y R nos lo muestra sin el formato del método print para esa clase: vemos los números completos. Acá tiene 7 decimales, dependerá de lo que estés haciendo que sea suficiente.

## Moraleja:

En R lo que **se ve** y lo que **es** no simpre lo mismo. Los sumarios y  métodos `print()` son prácticos para ver los resultados de un análisis porque salen bien formateados en pantalla, pero vale la pena asignar un nombre al resultado y explorarlo en profundidad. De ese modo podes usar la información que extraes de ahí para seguir con tu análisis, hacer gráficos, etc.

### Bonus track

Con la librería `psych` cargada probá:

```
corPlot(resultado_corr.test$p)
```